# php redeclaring use class

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to implement the new facebook php SDK, and while doing so i came across an issue, i dont quite understand.

I will include the code below in all of my files:

```
## Include.php
require_once("class/facebook_source/autoload.php");
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
```

In another file, i would then like to access some of the functions in for example FacebookRequest:

```
## FILE1.php
require("include.php");

$user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
  $session, 'GET', '/me'
))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
```

The thing is, FILE1.php will fail with an unknown class error.

I have found, that if i add:

```
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
```

to FILE1.php it WILL work

So my question is: Why it is nessecary to redeclare the classes even though i already did it in include.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is why you have to have **use** again in your second file. Read the last line.

> **Scoping rules for importing**
>
> Scoping rules for importing  The use keyword must be declared in the
> outermost scope of a file (the global scope) or inside namespace
> declarations. This is because the importing is done at compile time
> and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.
>
> **Note:**
>
> Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will NOT
> inherit the parent file's importing rules.

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)**

Please note that you are not *re declaring* the class, you are just re declaring the alias in the new scope.

Comment: Must have missed that. Thank you